# NSNotification query -- Recursive View Controller calls & registering for same notification multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

I have a question regarding the NSNotificationCenter. I have 3 view controllers who are registering for same push notification and flow of the app is like:

CASE 1:

1. View Controller 1 register for notification
2. View Controller 2 gets initialized and shown as modal from view controller 1
3. View Controller 2 register for notification
4. View Controller 3 gets initialized and shown as modal from view controller 2
5. View Controller 3 register for notification
6. Notification is fired

Is that all my view controllers (VC1, VC2 & VC3) will respond to this notification? I want only my topmost view controller respond to this notification. There will be separate firing of notification in case of other VC in the view hierarchy.

CASE 2:

1. View Controller 1 register for notification
2. View Controller 1 gets a self call and shown as modal on the previous view controller.
3. View Controller 1 again register for notification
4. Steps 2 & 3 gets repeated one more time.
5. Notification is fired

Here I want my top most VC to respond to this notification. There will be separate firing of notification in case of other VC in the view hierarchy.
 6. Notification is fired

Answer (score 1):

Every object (view controller) that has registered for a notification will receive it if it still exists (is on the navigation stack in the case of a view controller).

One solution is to **stop listening when a view controller disappears for example**, but you need to be careful that you start listening / stop listening in an appropriate pair of methods - so don't listen in the init and stop listening in the viewWillDisappear if you expect it to listen again when the user navigates back.

Also be prepared for view controllers on the navigation stack to unload / deallocate when memory gets low as they can be reconstituted on demand by the iOS.

Finally - don't register twice in the same view controller - you will receive the notification twice if you do that.

If you think about it this way, I'm sure you'll soon find a suitable solution in your case.

Comment: Hi Roger. You r right. Can you please see my idea below if you agree on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think another way can be sending some unique data in userInfo dictionary while posting the notification and then when all view controllers who registered for this notification can first check for this value and then proceed accordingly.

Comment: Sure, that's another way of doing it.